# Rails - How to remove the last comma in a hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, geojson

I have a each :

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
   <% @pois.each do |poi| %>
   {
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [<%= poi.longitude %>, <%= poi.latitude %> ]
   },
 <% end %>
 ]
}
```

I want to delete the last comma for the last iteration. How can I do  ?

It's not a json, but a Geojson.

I would have something like this :

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [2.484957, 44.6044089 ]
      },
      "properties": {}
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [2.3749903, 44.5656783 ]
      },
     "properties": {}
    }
  ]
}
```

All it's ok, I just want delete the last comma ;)

Comment: Is this a hash?

Comment: What is that? Where is that? Why are you doing that?

Comment: It's a Geojson ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are probably interested in transforming an array into another array, you can use `map` instead of `each`, i.e.,

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": 
   <% @pois.map do |poi| %>
     {
       "type": "Feature",
       "geometry": {
         "type": "Point",
         "coordinates": [<%= poi.longitude %>, <%= poi.latitude %> ]
       }
     }
   <% end %>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I presume you're trying to create/edit a JSON object of some sort.

You **should not** handle JSON objects in this manner.
Instead use the ActiveModel::Serializers

From [ActiveModel::Serializers](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON.html)

```
user = User.find(1)
user.as_json
# => { "id" => 1, "name" => "Konata Izumi", "age" => 16,
#     "created_at" => "2006/08/01", "awesome" => true}

ActiveRecord::Base.include_root_in_json = true

user.as_json
# => { "user" => { "id" => 1, "name" => "Konata Izumi", "age" => 16,
#                  "created_at" => "2006/08/01", "awesome" => true } }
```

Comment: @Ben Well you could compile a string array with those details in it then join the array with ','. Then there will be no trailing comma.